# Admob does not display

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-services

I have signed up on adMob and I got an app Id ,so ad suppose to appear in activity_main.xml but it just take a space without displaying any thing here is the code of activity_main.xml

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            tools:context="com.android.homeexercises.MainActivity"
            >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#0000"
   >
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

code in MainActivity class :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

code in manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.afai_aapps109.android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
       >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name="com.android.homeexercises.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

and the library in gradle :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the logcat. You should see something like

> failed to load ad: 3

The error code may be from 0 to 3.
Check the error code from the documentation from here. 
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL

Comment: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. _____
GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing google app id value from from string resources with name google_app_id.Missing google_app_id._______ Firebase Analytics disabled.that's what I found in the logcat , any suggestions ?

Comment: Check log carefully. That log is related to firebase analytics, not with ads. You can fix that firebase error by properly linking the file google-services.json.